# Get current authenticated user from JIRA REST api

Tags: jira-rest-api

The documentation and examples on the JIRA REST api that I've seen so far don't cover the case where you want to identify the currently logged in user on a particular host (having no prior information about them).

I want to do this so I can just say 'get all issues assigned to me', rather than 'get all issues assigned to Bob' (as I would have to know the username 'Bob' for this).

Is this possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to know the details of the current session (which also gives the user name) then the REST API URI path is **/rest/auth/latest/session**

Below is the JSON returned by the API

```
{

    "self": "<JIRA host>/rest/api/latest/user?username=bob",
    "name": "Bob",
    "loginInfo": {
        "failedLoginCount": 1,
        "loginCount": 2,
        "lastFailedLoginTime": "2011-11-17T19:27:50.097-0800",
        "previousLoginTime": "2011-11-20T19:06:58.412-0800"
    }

}
```

Comment: This is working for me on Postman, but not when I implement the query on a script sending it via ajax, getting ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

`GET {jira_url}/rest/api/latest/myself`

This will return the logged in user details, the same response as from

`GET {jira_url}/rest/api/latest/user?username=<username>`

but without specifying the username.